# Group By in SQL/Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying an efficient way to run a query in hive.

Consider i have 2 columns: `event, date_in_ist`

`date_in_ist` is in string in the format: `yyyy-mm-dd`

I am looking to find the number of unique users per month in the following format: (Event should be in (`"app_opened","app_access","app_access"`)

```
Event   Month-Year  Count_Users
 a       09-2017       50
 a       02-2017       100
 b       09-2018       40
```

Help will be appreciated

Comment: You do not have enough information to find *unique* users, because your table does not have information on which user is associated with each event.

Comment: You're right.
I missed a column
There is a column: distinct_id
How would the query look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select event,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_in_ist,'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                    'MM-yyyy') as 'Month-Year',count(*) as count_users
from tablename
where eveent in ('app_opened','app install','app_access','app launched')
group by event,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_in_ist,'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                    'MM-yyyy')
```

Comment: date_in_ist is in string
I think we would need to cast it into date.
Moreover, i only need 4 events: app install, app access, app launched out of all the 100's of events.

Comment: @AmanGupta, I've modified my answer and added where clause with in

Comment: I am getting the following error:
FAILED: ParseException line 2:39 missing EOF at '-' near 'Month'

Comment: Hey fa06,
The query ran but it is just returning me results from 01-2017 and 01-2018
Have a look:

event   month-year      count_users
App Access      01-2018 4127745930
App Launched    01-2017 6184866
App Opened      01-2017 4842318
App Install     01-2018 65195236
App Opened      01-2018 590852137
App Install     01-2017 9270856
App Access      01-2017 646319858
App Launched    01-2018 20122876

Comment: @AmanGupta,  I believe the template should be 'yyyy-MM-dd', not 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0):

Use `'yyyy-MM-dd'`,template, not `'yyyy-mm-dd'`:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_in_ist,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM-yyyy') as 'Month-Year'
```

Or you can use concat_ws and substr:

```
select event,
       concat_ws('-',substr(date_in_ist,6,2),substr(date_in_ist,1,4)) as 'Month-Year',
       count(*) as count_users
from tablename
where eveent in ('app_opened','app install','app_access','app launched')
group by event,
         concat_ws('-',substr(date_in_ist,6,2),substr(date_in_ist,1,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would return the date as yyyy-mm, and use simple aggregation:

```
select event, substr(date_in_ist, 1, 7) as yyyy_mm
       count(distinct user_id) as count_users
from t
where event in ('app_opened','app install','app_access','app launched')
group by event, substr(date_in_ist, 1, 7);
```